# Unable to target css class with react in cloud 9 ide

Tags: css, reactjs, cloud9-ide

There is a div with the class name of "live-channel-item-info". I'm trying to make this div have a display of flex.

I can target elements in my css code just fine, but when I try to target them by class, it's not working. I can't

I have tried to increase my css specificity. I have also tried to change className to just class. I have also tried changing the quotes surrounding the class name from double quotes to single quotes.

RecommendedLiveChannels.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from '../../dist/styles/recommendedLiveChannels.css';

export default function RecommendedLiveChannels() {
  return (
    <section>
      <h2>Recommended live channels</h2>
      <ul class='live-channels-list'>
        <li className='live-channel-item'>
          <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/275' alt='video image' />
          <div className='live-channel-item-info'>
            <img src='https://via.placeholder.com/40' alt='album-image' />
            <div className='live-channel-item-info-text'>
              <h3>Tribal E-Tour November 15 2020</h3>
              <p>Vinivici</p>
              <p>Psychodelic-Trance</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
}
```

RecommendedLiveChannels.css:

```
h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.live-channel-item-info {
  display: flex;
}
```

I'm trying to get the div with the class name "live-channel-item-info" to have a display of flex, but it's not showing up. Even in the dev console I don't see the rule being applied and striked out.

Comment: It's striked out because a declaration of higher specificity overrides it. Type `display` in the `Filter` box at the top to find what selector applies the current value for `display` property, where from and (obviously) what specificity your selector needs to have in order to override it.

Comment: This is just React - not React Native. You might want to edit the title for better assistance

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Jonathan, it's React. Let me look into the specificity issue real quick again.

Comment: I apologize for the late update, it turns out that webpack was changing my class names on compile. I ended up rebooting the project using create react app since I'm a little more familiar with that and now my css class selections are working just fine. Thanks for everything guys.